# ruby on rails tutorial - rails server issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I've just started doing the "Ruby on Rails Tutorial", from Michael Hartl. I've created a new project with:

```
rails new first_app
```

Then he had me change the `Gemfile` from:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.1'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.
# Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

To this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
```

Now when I try to run `rails server`, I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Thomas\rails_projects\first_app> rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Users/Thomas/rails_projects/first_app/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `c
onfigure' for #<FirstApp::Application:0x2a2bae8> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb
:229:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb
:229:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb
:214:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb
:229:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 le
vels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <c
lass:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `insta
nce_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block
 in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_com
ponent'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_com
ponent_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort
_each_child'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_i
nitializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initia
lize!'
        from C:/Users/Thomas/rails_projects/first_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/Thomas/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Thomas/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/Thomas/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Users/Thomas/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'

        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_op
tions_from_config'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `sta
rt'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <
top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (requ
ired)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I know the error occurs from changing the `Gemfile` because it works before I change it. I want to follow Michael as closely as possible. The only different is that I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and he is using Ruby 2.0, though in the book he said if not using 2 just change that in the `Gemfile` which I did.

Comment: you haven't changed the ruby in the gemfile...

Comment: Sorry I'm being a noob here, I did change it just pasted the old code by accident.

Answer (score 1):

You need change in **app/config/initializers/development.rb** line

```
Rails.application.configure do
```

to

```
YourApp::Application.configure do
```

but you will see the error:

**Internal Server Error You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config**

To solve this problem you should generate a rnd secret key

```
$ rake secret
```

then create file **config/initializers/secret_token.rb** and put into this file

```
YourApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'
```

where YOUR_SECRET_KEY is prev generated and all goes ok.

The reason is because of new convention to store secret key (Upgrading from Rails 4.0 to Rails 4.1 [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#action-pack))

P.S. Pay attention to file **config/secrets.yml**.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring ruby '2.0.0' at the begin of the Gemfile but you are using 1.9.3 so it will fail when trying to detect it. Change to ruby '1.9.3'

Also you might need to run bundle in order to install the gems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the ruby line completely? I don't usually have this line in my gemfile

Comment: have you rerun bundle install, and then tried bundle exec rails s

Comment: also whats in the first 2 lines of your development.rb file?

Comment: Rails.application.configure do
    
  config.cache_classes = false

Comment: and yeah i tried bundle update, bundle install. I just tried bundle exec rails s and I got the same error again

Comment: Rails.application.configure do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388205/rails-generate-scaffold-error/23388766#23388766

Comment: Thanks Florian, I changed the first line and the rails server went through without an error. Then i went to localhost:3000 and i am getting the error...
You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config. 

also can you explain why i needed to change the development file?
ty

Answer (score 0):

This is the error you're receiving:

```
C:/Users/Thomas/rails_projects/first_app/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for #<FirstApp::Application:0x2a2bae8>
```

It basically means you have an error on `line 1` of the file `/config/environments/development.rb`

--

You mention the error disappears when you change your Gemfile. I suspect the issue is you've not got `Ruby 1.9.3` installed on your system, confusing Rails & preventing it from loading

My recommendation is to (re)install `Ruby 1.9.3` or `Ruby 2.0.0` on your system

Comment: Thanks Rich, I used rail yards quick installer. I have reinstalled ruby a few times and still no luck.
When i type ruby -v, it says ruby 1.9.3 is installed

Comment: Hmm okay, can you detail which line in your `Gemfile` you're getting the error from? That would be a big help

Comment: Also, are there any dependencies you're using which rely on Ruby 2.0?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find that. I watch two ruby items pop up in task manager when i hit rails server, and then they disappear. Everything seems to work up until rails server.
I get the feeling that there are dependencies, all the gems are very version specific. Maybe ill just switch to version two even though he recommends 1.9.3, and then puts 2 code haha.

Comment: What about your Gemfile? Which line allows you to run the server?

Comment: I had rails at version 4.1.1 installed globally. I replaced my Gemfile with what was shown in the book, so it loaded rails 4.0.8 locally. This gave me that error too. I just switched the rails version in the Gemfile to 4.1.1, bundle update and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Check your rails version by

> rails -v

Then in your Gemfile of your app change make sure
you have the version of rails with accordance to the
one you have on your computer in my case it was:

> gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

Now finally run

> bundle update
>   bundle install

Now you should be able to run your server.